# How to upload images to S3 bucket if it doesn't already exist

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have a python script running to upload images to s3 bucket every hour.
The images coming in are of three types and the script creates a specific folder based on name of image and then uploads images to that folder in S3 based on image name.

What's happening now is that every hour the same images are getting overwritten in the bucket, I need to upload images only if it doesn't exist already
How can I achieve this.
Please help through

```
import os.path, shutil
import os, time
import socket
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
import glob
import json
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


id = id_of_file
def my_schedule():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id="Access_key",
                aws_secret_access_key="Secret_key")

    folder_path = "path"
    images = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]
    for image in images:
        print(image)
        folder_name = image.split('-')[0]
        print(folder_name)
        print("folder created**********************************")
        key = "%s/%s" % (id+ '/' + folder_name, os.path.basename(image))
        objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))
        print("Putting %s as %s" % (image, key))
        final_file = folder_path + image
        s3.upload_file(final_file, Bucket, key)

    print("ALL Images uploaded successfully to s3 bucket")
    time.sleep(5)

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(my_schedule, 'interval', hours=1)
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: How do you want to check it? You could simply remove the local files once they have been uploaded. Or you could call `head_object()` for each object before it is uploaded, to check whether it exists. Or, you could retrieve a list of objects in the bucket and compare them against a list of local objects. Or, instead of writing a script, you could simply use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command with some [include/exclude filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) to do it for you!

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, thank you for the response. I just want to know if it is possible to change the overwriting permission for a specific bucket through AWS ???

Comment: What do you mean by "change the overwriting permission"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I was just wondering if we can prevent the folder contents from getting overwritten?? Is there any way to do that by giving some sort of permission.
.As of now I'm deleting the local storage images once uploaded to S3

Comment: There is no way to prevent an object in S3 from being overwritten. If a user has permission to `PutObject` (create the object), then it also grants permission to replace an existing object. If Versioning is enabled, then prior versions will be kept and can be accessed, but it does not prevent the upload.

Comment: ok sure then, I guess deleting as soon as uploaded is the best way

Comment: Or, as mentioned, you can use the AWS CLI that has a `sync` command to do it all for you automatically. It will only copy files that are new or changed.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ok sure, Thanks alot for your help :)